# Cannot create HERE SDK object before MapEngine is initialized. See MapEngine.init()

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am getting the `com.here.android.mpa.common.UnintializedMapEngineException` error. That states:

> Cannot create HERE SDK object before MapEngine is initialized. See MapEngine.init()

The code has been taken from Here Maps own example on [GitHub](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/geocoder-and-reverse-geocoder).

In my MainActivity I am calling `geoCodeAddress("some address")` that is when the error is thrown.

I am using HERE SDK Version: 3.11.2.82

**Can anyone see what I am might be doing wrong?**

**Manifest**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
        android:value="MyAppIdHere" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
        android:value="MyAppTokenHere" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
        android:value="MyKeyHere" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="INTENT_NAME"
        android:value="HereMappingIntent" />

    <service
        android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="HereMapping">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="HereMappingIntent"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**HereGeocoder.java**

```
public class HereGeoCoder {
    private String                TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private IHereGeoCoderListener mListener;
    private AppCompatActivity     mActivity;

    public HereGeoCoder(AppCompatActivity activity, IHereGeoCoderListener listener) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mListener = listener;
        initMapEngine();
    }

    private void initMapEngine() {
        String diskCacheRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + ".isolated-here-maps";
        String intentName = "";
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai     = mActivity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(mActivity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Bundle          bundle = ai.metaData;
            intentName = bundle.getString("INTENT_NAME");
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Failed to find intent name, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(diskCacheRoot, intentName);
        if (!success) {

        } else {

            MapEngine.getInstance().init(new ApplicationContext(mActivity), new OnEngineInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
                //Here is 
                    Log.e(TAG, "Map Engine initialized with error code: " + error);
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Map Engine initialized with error code:" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void getCoordinatesForAddress(String address) {
        GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest(address);
        geocodeRequest.execute(new ResultListener<List<GeocodeResult>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GeocodeResult> results, ErrorCode errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == ErrorCode.NONE) {
                    if (results.size() > 0) {
                        HashMap<String, Double> coords = new HashMap<>();
                        GeocodeResult           result = results.get(0);
                        coords.put("Latitude", result.getLocation().getCoordinate().getLatitude());
                        coords.put("Longitude", result.getLocation().getCoordinate().getLongitude());
                        if (mListener != null) {
                            mListener.onDidDecodeAddress(coords);
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---- UPDATED

**IHereGeoCoderListener.java**

```
public interface IHereGeoCoderListener {
    void onDidDecodeAddress(HashMap<String, Double> coordinates);

    void onDidDecodeCoordiantes(String address);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String   TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private final static int      REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    private static final String[] RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS          = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //PERMSSIONS
        if (!hasPermissions(this, RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        }

        geoCodeAddress("1 Broad St, Chattanooga, TN 37402");

    }


    //PERMISSIONS
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS: {
                for (int index = 0; index < permissions.length; index++) {
                    if (grantResults[index] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        /*
                         * If the user turned down the permission request in the past and chose the
                         * Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog.
                         */
                        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permissions[index])) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Required permission " + permissions[index] + " not granted. Please go to settings and turn on for sample app",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Required permission " + permissions[index] + " not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    // GEOCODER
    private void geoCodeAddress(String address) {
        if (hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //GEOCODER
            HereGeoCoder geoCoder = new HereGeoCoder(this, new IHereGeoCoderListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDidDecodeAddress(HashMap<String, Double> coordinates) {
                    for (HashMap.Entry<String, Double> entry : coordinates.entrySet()) {
                         Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s,%s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDidDecodeCoordiantes(String address) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onDidDecodeCoordinates: " + address);
                }
            });

            geoCoder.getCoordinatesForAddress(address);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You do not have the correct permissions set.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also post the contents of MainActivity and IHereGeocoderListerner classes? The default example code on GitHub does not show a map engine initialization error.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport See updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to execute a geocode request before the map engine is completely initialised. I have adapted your code with the fix:
**HereGeoCoder.java**

```
    public class HereGeoCoder {
    private String                TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private IHereGeoCoderListener mListener;
    private AppCompatActivity     mActivity;
    private String                mAddress;

    public HereGeoCoder(AppCompatActivity activity, String address, IHereGeoCoderListener listener) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mAddress = address;
        initMapEngine();
    }

    private void initMapEngine() {
        String diskCacheRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + ".isolated-here-maps";
        String intentName = "";
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai     = mActivity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(mActivity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Bundle          bundle = ai.metaData;
            intentName = bundle.getString("INTENT_NAME");
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Failed to find intent name, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(diskCacheRoot, intentName);
        if (!success) {

        } else {

            MapEngine.getInstance().init(new ApplicationContext(mActivity), new OnEngineInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
                //Here is 
                    Log.e(TAG, "Map Engine initialized with error code: " + error);
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Map Engine initialized with error code:" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   if (error == Error.NONE) {
                      getCoordinatesForAddress(mAddress);
                   }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void getCoordinatesForAddress(String address) {
        GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest(address);
        geocodeRequest.execute(new ResultListener<List<GeocodeResult>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GeocodeResult> results, ErrorCode errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == ErrorCode.NONE) {
                    if (results.size() > 0) {
                        HashMap<String, Double> coords = new HashMap<>();
                        GeocodeResult           result = results.get(0);
                        coords.put("Latitude", result.getLocation().getCoordinate().getLatitude());
                        coords.put("Longitude", result.getLocation().getCoordinate().getLongitude());
                        if (mListener != null) {
                            mListener.onDidDecodeAddress(coords);
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `geoCodeAddress` function in the MainActivity:

```
// GEOCODER
    private void geoCodeAddress(String address) {
        if (hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //GEOCODER
            HereGeoCoder geoCoder = new HereGeoCoder(this, address, new IHereGeoCoderListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDidDecodeAddress(HashMap<String, Double> coordinates) {
                    for (HashMap.Entry<String, Double> entry : coordinates.entrySet()) {
                         Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s,%s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDidDecodeCoordiantes(String address) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onDidDecodeCoordinates: " + address);
                }
            });

            //geoCoder.getCoordinatesForAddress(address);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You do not have the correct permissions set.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You implementation locks the class into one function `getCodeAddress`. The `HereGeoCoder` can't be extended. My original code came straight from the Here example. 
@HEREDeveloperSupport

Comment: My adaptation of your code was just to show you why you are getting the error (Like I said: you are trying to execute a geocode request before the map engine is completely initialised). In original code of HERE, the geocode executor is called when the map and the UI elements are fully initialized. So just make sure `MapEngine.getInstance().init()` is done (i.e `onEngineInitializationCompleted()` is called before you try to execute a Geocode request.

Comment: This code is exactly like the Example code. If you were to run the GeoCode Reverse GeoCode example, you get the same error.

Comment: Sorry but the geocoder-and-reverse-geocoder code has been run without a Map engine initialization error.

Comment: I've run the geocoder-and-reverse-geocoder from github and it throws the same error as above.